# How to remove duplicated rows based on 3 columns for only one factor level?

Tags: r

[image]

I have a list of `130` dataframes each with `27` columns and `2` factor levels per dataframe. I want to remove the duplicated rows in each dataframe based on `3` columns for one factor level only, keeping all rows in the other factor level and their duplicates.

I have sorted all the dataframes according to the factor levels and then I tried to remove the duplicated rows only for the first factor level.

The list is called `x` and `i` index between the dataframes in list with `x[[i]]`, with `i` running from `1` to `130`.

[image]

[image]

The column in every dataframe called `temp` contains `2` factor levels, either `0` or `1`. The `130` dataframes have been ordered according to `level = 0` first and then `level=1`.

```
for (i in 1:130)
{
x[[i]]$temp <- factor(x[[i]]$temp,levels = c(0,1)) 

# Creating 2 factor levels called `0` and `1` in column called `temp` and index position of the `temp` column is `24`

x[[i]] <- x[[i]][order(x[[i]]$temp),] 

# Ordering all of the dataframes by levels; level = 0 first then level = 1

x[[i]] <- x[[i]][!(duplicated(x[[i]][c(2,27,25)])),] 

# This is removing duplicated based on columns 2,27 and 25, but I to perform this only for the first factor level = 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible (simulated) example? Note that you can format your question to include the code chunks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and edit your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single data frame, say `df`, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(temp, 2, 27, 25, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Note that you don't have to consider grouping on your factor, because if you have rows for both factors with repeated values for columns 2, 27 and 25, they are still two distinct columns.

The key here is the argument `.keep_all`, which keeps the remaining columns. Note however that if the remaining columns differ in some why, it is undetermined *which* rows you get back, you just get 1 row for each distinct combination of `temp` and columns 2, 27 and 25.

To expand to a list of data.frames, you can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(x, function(df) {
  df %>% distinct(temp, 2, 27, 25, .keep_all = TRUE)
}) %>% bind_rows(.id='date')
```

where the last call to `bind_rows` simply compresses everything into a single data frame, with the added `.id` argument to add a column named `date` whose values should be the entry names in your input list.